# Swift Passing Class Method as Parameter vs Closure

Tags: swift, coding-style, retain-cycle

I have a question regarding a potential retain cycle in a given situation.

```
public struct MasterItem {
    public let itemTitle: String!
    public var itemImage: UIImage?
    public let itemCallback: ((MasterItem) -> Void)!
    public let ord: Int!

    public init(itemTitle: String, itemImage: UIImage?, ord: Int = Int.min, itemCallback: (MasterItem) -> Void) {
        self.itemTitle = itemTitle
        self.itemImage = itemImage
        self.itemCallback = itemCallback
        self.ord = ord
    }
}

class MasterDetail: FKMasterDetailViewController {

    let master = FKMasterViewController(items: [])

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        let arr: [MasterItem] = [
            MasterItem(itemTitle: "Bob",  itemImage: UIImage(), ord: 1, itemCallback: self.menuItemTapped),
            MasterItem(itemTitle: "Fred", itemImage: UIImage(), ord: 2, itemCallback: self.menuItemTapped),
            MasterItem(itemTitle: "Jedd", itemImage: UIImage(), ord: 3, itemCallback: self.menuItemTapped)
        ]
        for item in arr { self.master.addMasterItem(item) }
    }

    func menuItemTapped(item: MasterItem) {
        //reference self in here
    }
}
```

My question is, will there be a retain cycle in this situation, or will the app crash when the non optional property `itemCallback` on `MasterItem` gets set to `nil` if `MasterDetail` gets dereferenced. The reason why this may be relevant is because the function `menuItemTapped` could theoretically be useful to have as a class method rather than just a property that is a closure.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `FKMasterViewController` holds onto its `items`, yes, there are retain cycles.

`self.menuItemTapped` is just syntactic sugar for

```
{ x in self.menuItemTapped(x) }
```

If you know the `FKMasterViewController` and its `items` and callbacks will only exist in the context of this `FKMasterDetailViewController`, then the closure should capture a weak reference to the `FKMasterDetailViewController`:

```
{ [unowned self] x in self.menuItemTapped(x) }
```

or

```
{ [weak self] x in self?.menuItemTapped(x) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Did you test this to find out? Or is it mentioned in the docs somewhere?